# How to implement VBA All Sorts in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been given a task, where there is a group of people in a excel spreadsheet, in which the owner can mark if a person has arrived or not. Which can be done in excel by using VBA All Sorts. But I don't how to implement this in Google Sheets. Is there some workaround to this?

I I have tried looking at the documentation for google-script-apps, and various how-to guides of designing a userform for a Google Sheets document.

I am afraid, that I can't provide some code as I haven't a clue of how to implement VBA All Sorts in Google Sheets.

Comment: What does VBA All Sorts do?

Comment: @Cooper It basically allows me to find all matches, when searching for some sort of information in a textbox. Such as a name, in which the program allows me to answer if a person has arrived or not.

Comment: There is a textfinder Class that I think is implemented in spreadsheets or sheets

Answer (score 0):

what you should look into is Google Web Apps. You can create an HTML page with Google Spreadsheet as database. You can create the HTML page with all the options you want and then write/read the data from Google Spreadsheet by calling Javascript functions in the HTML talking to google.script.run.XXXX() Google Apps Script functions.